# li tag with conditional always not visble in angular test with jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, angular-ng-if

Good day developers . Im trying to test the show hide behaviour of a `<li/>` tag  according to a specific variable.

For that this `<li/>` tag has an `*ngIf` bound:

```
      <ul class="item" js-selector="tab-list">
        <li class="item" js-selector="tab"
          *ngIf="isTabEnabled"
          ...
        >
        </li>
      </ul>
```

then on my component tha variable this li tag is bound to would be like this:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: '',
})
export class Component implements OnInit{
    public isTabEnabled: boolean;

  constructor() {
        this.isTabEnabled = false;
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
     this.isTabEnabled = true/false =======> boolean value of a feature flag
  }


}
```

thus in my test:

```
describe('The Component', () => {
  
  let page: Page;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
     
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          ...
        ],
        declarations: [
          Component,
          ComponentStub,
        ],
       
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;

          page = new Page();
        });
    })
  );

   describe('When test ....',()=>{
     it('Should show  Tab if feature flag  is enabled', () => {
        const  tab = page.getTab();
       
        fixture.detectChanges();
  
        component.isTabEnabled=true
      
        expect(tab).toBeVisible();
      });

      it('Should not show  Tab if feature flag  is not enabled', () => {
        const  tab = page.getTab();
       
        fixture.detectChanges();
  
        component.isTabEnabled=false
      
        expect(tab).not.toBeVisible();
      });
   
   }

   class Page {
    private _el: HTMLElement;

    constructor() {
      this._el = fixture.nativeElement;
    }

    getTab(): HTMLElement {
      return this._el.querySelector('[js-selector="tab"]');
    } }
});
```

But i keep receiving this  error

```
 Received element is not visible:
      <li class="item" js-selector="tab"  />
```

Could you help me on this simple test...find the problem of its fail.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing a `fixture.detectChanges` after changing `isTabEnabled` and getting the reference to the HTML element too early.

Try this:

```
it('Should show  Tab if feature flag  is enabled', () => {
        // !! first fixture.detectChanges() calls ngOnInit
        fixture.detectChanges();
  
        component.isTabEnabled=true;
        // !! call fixture.detectChanges() again so the view updates with the
        // new value of isTabEnabled
        fixture.detectChanges();
        !! get the value of the HTML element now
        const  tab = page.getTab();
        expect(tab).toBeVisible();
      });
       // !! same thing here
      it('Should not show  Tab if feature flag  is not enabled', () => {
       
        fixture.detectChanges();
  
        component.isTabEnabled=false
        
        fixture.detectChanges();

        const tab = page.getTab();

        expect(tab).not.toBeVisible();
      });
```